# watchOS get activity data

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-3

How can I go about capturing daily activity data from Apple Watch at a high level (gyroscope and accelerometer data) or is that not possible (due to current limitations of the API)?

I am trying to figure out a way to find all occurrences of a custom workout performed during the day by a watch user. User installs the app, grants permissions where applicable. Launches daily to see workouts performed in the last day. The app pulls data, stores it, analyzes it and plots necessary metrics.

I want to know if this is possible - pulling data on launch to run analysis. If so, how?

I see [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/SwingWatch) example from Apple on recording counts swings in a racquet sport but that seems to require instantiating and stopping various `CoreMotion` events such as `startDeviceMotionUpdates` and `stopDeviceMotionUpdates` in order for the app to retrieve them.

Any pointers?

Comment: Probably relevant: https://github.com/shu223/watchOS-2-Sampler